# Legacy hardware 32 bit linux

Tags: linux, 32bit, hardware-compatibility

I've been provided with what appears to be a functional PIII Dell Dimension L667r with a whopping 128M of RAM. Further complicating the issue is this system appears to be unable to boot off USB and has only a CDROM available to install from. In a likely futile effort to save this ancient beast from the landfill, I'm looking for a lightweight 32-bit linux with a GUI that is capable of installing and running on a system with these rather restricted specifications. I tried to install Debian 11.4 32 bit which resulted in a notification that 257M of RAM was required to install it.I was able to install tinycore, but it seems a bit too much trouble to setup and use for a probable recipient of this machine. I was able to install bionicpup32-8.0-uefi, which appears to dislike the video. Ideally, I'd like to find a light linux that at least has the 'lshw' command so that I can determine how to overcome the issues I'm encountering with this old beast.  I'd pull the drive and place it in another machine so that I could improve my chances of success by creating a swap partition, but the hdd technology is pre-SATA (IDE) and I don't have a system old enough to support the drive other than this one.Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: you might get better chance on [retrocomputing.se]. But running Linux in such HW, especially with GUI is a bad idea. You should use another OS instead and/or run CLI only

Comment: [Is possible to boot Ubuntu with less than 128MB of RAM?](https://askubuntu.com/q/392155/253474), [Command Line Linux Distro for i386 and 128MB RAM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27940/44425), [Linux for 128 MB of memory](https://superuser.com/q/111488/241386)

Comment: @phuclv I disagree about the choice of OS. An older version of GNU/Linux would be able to run on older hardware. As an example, around 1999 I used a version of Slackware on i386 with 4MB of RAM without issues. It was able to run X, albeit that was slow.

Comment: Check from here https://itsfoss.com/32-bit-linux-distributions/

Comment: @Vilinkameni and then what do you do with that GUI? Surf the web? Definitely not at all, because such old versions are insecure and doesn't support many newer technologies so lots of websites will completely block them. Watching videos? They don't even have enough power for 720p

Comment: @phuclv That wasn't a requirement. This kind of hardware was made much earlier than the technologies you describe, and I doubt that would be even possible with them at all.

Comment: @Vilinkameni who said that? Video editing has been there since the 80s. Document editing is one use case, but newer versions of libre office are very heavy, and old Open office is terrible about compatibility. Viewing photos is possible but the speed would also be unacceptable. Gaming is out of the question with ancient Linux

Comment: @phuclv You mentioned watching videos and surfing the (current) Web. :) 720p digital video editing was definitely *not* around at the time of i386. Even during the days of early home-used WWW (around 1995), that processor was considered old. Modern web is post-2000. The question was about running an OS at all, with a GUI. :)